# Powershell loop Get-mailbox

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm writing a foreach loop script I've done this before but this script is giving me a problem.  It works when I manually enter the name but when I try and pull from a txt file I get errors.

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox joerod

foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) 
 { 
 $user = $mailbox.alias 
 Write-Host "Processing... $user" 
 $mailbox.EmailAddresses += [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.CustomProxyAddress] ("X500:/o=OrgName/ou=First Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=$user") 
 Set-Mailbox -Identity $mailbox.alias -EmailAddresses $mailbox.EmailAddresses 
 }
```

Comment: You need to be lot clearer and more specific. Manually enter what name, and how? Pull from a text file how? What errors are you getting? (Don't describe them, post them)

Comment: I was trying to pull from a text using get-content and it was not working, it would use the first user name and try and join it to other names.

Comment: my question was how do I run through a list of names and insert each name after `Get-Mailbox`

Answer (score 1):

Added the following line and got what I was looking for

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "ou=users,dc=contoso,dc=local"
```